# Matching against ID and copying cells of other column as a block to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I got a Sheet1 looking like this:
[image]

And what I want to do is that I copy the amounts where the ID matches the ID I am looking for (here 3) into another Sheet.
So my result in Sheet 2 would look like this:
[image]

Any ideas on how to do that? I think Excel VBA is necessary (would be awesome if its not needed though) and I also thought about using SQL expression in VBA.

Thanks

Comment: Just another idea: Filter the columns for `3` in column *ID* then copy the *Amount* and paste it into *sheet 2*. (could be done with VBA). Another approach is looping through column *ID* (with VBA) and copy each *Amount* if the ID matches. (loop might be faster that filtering in some cases if speed is an issue)

Comment: In Google Sheets, you can achieve this by `query` built-in function like this: `=query($B:$D, "select D where B = "&$B$13)`. Sample sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1guo5IFkvTYkjDz4vMPilbJEt7cZ7Dd1a_Mm-4Jofem0/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `id`s are on `B2:B10` and `amount`s are on `D2:D10` and the value to find is on `B13`, this **array formula** will get multiple matches:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(D$3:D$10, SMALL(IF(B$3:B$10=$B$13, ROW(B$3:B$10)-MIN(ROW(B$3:B$10))+1), ROW(E$3:E$10)-2)), "")}
```

[image]

Note that the last `E$3:E$10` can be an any column. This method is from [this article](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-multiple-matches-into-separate-columns), which explains the formula very kindly.

Also, as I commented, in Google Sheets, you can achieve this by more simple `query()` function:

```
=query($B:$D, "select D where B = "&$B$13)
```